# async loading in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the following situation.

EntryA

```
require("./test.js");
```

EntryB

```
require("./test.js");
```

test.js

```
module.exports = "something";
```

I want tuse webpack to compile these javascript files. On the html page i just want to include the EntryA.js. Every thing that is common between EntryA and EntryB should come in a sperate file. Now, when test.js is required, that common file should be downloaded from the net.

is this possible and ghow should i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack offers two ways to split out your JS.

1. Use [multiple entry points](https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html) (As you have done).
2. Define [split points](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) via `require.ensure` (or `System.import` in Webpack 2).

Approach 1 is really intended to be used by traditional 'multi' page websites and requires you to import the appropriate entry point on the correct page. NOTE: You can use the [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin) to extract out all the shared code but it still must be manually referenced.

Approach 2 is more geared towards single page apps and will automatically load in new scripts as necessary.